# Java communication via sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to implement basic TCP communication via sockets and the problem is that it doesn't work. When I enter few sentences from client, the server receives only the first sentence and reply it back.

Client :

```
String sentence;
    String modifiedSentence;
    BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 5055);
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    while(!(sentence = inFromUser.readLine()).equals("end")) {
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
        modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
    }
    clientSocket.close();
```

Server:

```
String clientSentence;
    String capitalizedSentence;
    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(5055);

    while (true) {
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
        capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
        outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
    }
```

Comment: Your server waits for a connection, reads one line, then waits for a new connection. You are trying to send multiple lines from your client with only one connection. Either make your client open a new connection for each line you want to send or have your server continue to read until it knows it has reached the end of input.

Comment: So line Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept() should be before while, right ? I checked it and it works

Comment: With that setup your server will only respond to one request and then quit. Not much of a server at that point.